# Get RSA Public key from Private key using WebCrypto Api

Tags: javascript, cryptography, diffie-hellman, webcrypto-api

I`m trying create session key using Diffie - Hellman algorithm for two users in JavaScript.
So now I have my cert.crt and bundle.crt and can`t find any example how to extract public and private keys from them using JavaScript only.
Cert and bundle format look like this: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----tkogtkgt...g858gm-----END CERTIFICATE----- (values in both files are not equal, it`s just an example)
Please Help!

Update:
I found out that certificate doesn`t contain private key and I was able to find the rsa private key for this certificate. Now i`m curious is it possible to get rsa public key from rsa private key using only WebCrypto api in browser?

Comment: Certificates don't contain private keys.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Is it possible to get the private key or public key is the only option for me?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know where you got these certificates, if you received them with the private key attached, what you're trying to achieve, etc.

Comment: However, Diffie-Hellman requires both parties to maintain a secre, and public keys, as the name indicates, are not secret.

Comment: `is it possible to get rsa public key from rsa private key using only WebCrypto api in browser?`  Yes.  Use `SubtleCrypto.importKey()` to import the private key into a CryptoKey object.  The CryptoKey object will actually contain both the private key and the public key.  Then, use SubtleCrypto.exportKey() to export the public key from the CryptoKey object.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807959/generate-public-key-from-private-key-using-webcrypto-api for an example.