# How to derive public key from private key using WebCryptoApi?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, webcrypto-api

The private key is generated using Elliptic Curve.
None of the methods from the [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/) interface of the Web Crypto API seem to be able to derive a public key from a private key, correct me if I'm wrong. Do I have to use a 3rd party library for that?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no support. However, this can easily be done by exporting and importing as JWK, removing the private part before importing.

Comment: I'll clarify: When I generate a key pair with subtle.generateKeys, I want to be able to recover the public key having only the private key saved.

Comment: In my answer you will find an implementation that illustrates the suggested approach. Without a third party library this is the easiest way.

Comment: Maxim, we had the same question, and it appears it's not possible natively in the Web Crypto API.  If this changes, please send me a message (I'm Zamicol everywhere) and let me know.  We'll update our libraries with native support.

Answer (score 6):

WebCrypto is a low level API with only a relatively small feature set. To my knowledge there is no dedicated method for deriving a public key from a private key.

However, you can export the private `CryptoKey` as JWK (JSON Web Key), remove the private portions, and re-import the remaining portion, which thereby becomes the public `CryptoKey`. The following code shows this for an ECDSA key:

```js
async function getPublic(privateKey){
    const jwkPrivate = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", privateKey);    
    delete jwkPrivate.d;
    jwkPrivate.key_ops = ["verify"];
    return crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", jwkPrivate, {name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256"}, true, ["verify"]);
}

async function test(){

    // Generate test key pair
    const keyPair = await crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256"}, true, ["sign", "verify"]);

    // Derive public from private key
    const publicKeyFromPrivate = await getPublic(keyPair.privateKey)

    // Compare CryptoKeys
    console.log(keyPair.publicKey);
    console.log(publicKeyFromPrivate)

    // Compare keys (in JWK format)
    const jwkPublic = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", keyPair.publicKey);
    const jwkPublicFromPrivate = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", publicKeyFromPrivate);
    console.log(jwkPublic);
    console.log(jwkPublicFromPrivate);
}

(async () => {
    await test()
})();
```

As you can see, the original and the reconstructed public key are identical.

However, it should be mentioned that this solutin has one drawback: the private key must be exportable.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571350/9014097) shows the same approach for RSA.

Comment: not sure if this changed recently, but afaik public keys need to have an empty array for usages  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74112616/2919380

Comment: @gotjosh - This post is about **ECDSA**. With ECDSA, the public key is used for verification and thus *verify* is to be applied for the key usage. In contrast, the linked post is about **ECDH**. With ECDH, the public key is used to derive the shared secret and in this context an *empty* key usage is to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

the noble curves library also [has functions for that](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apaulmillr%2Fnoble-curves%20fromprivate&type=code) :

```js
// export and extract private key 
const { d } = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", privateKey);

// transforms url encoded base64 string from the jwk into big number
const validPrivateKey = b64ToBn(urlBase64ToBase64(d)) 

// get x,y from the noble curves lib ProjectivePoint
const pointFromPK = p256.ProjectivePoint.fromPrivateKey(validPrivateKey)

// import using constructed public key jwk x,y
crypto.subtle.importKey(
   "jwk", 
   {  
      x: base64ToUrlBase64(bnToB64(pointFromPK.x)),
      y: base64ToUrlBase64(bnToB64(pointFromPK.y)),
   },
   {name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256"}, true, [/*must be empty for public keys*/]
)
```

support [functions from coolaj](https://coolaj86.com/articles/bigints-and-base64-in-javascript/)

```js
function b64ToBn(b64) {
  var bin = atob(b64);
  var hex = [];

  bin.split('').forEach(function (ch) {
    var h = ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    if (h.length % 2) { h = '0' + h; }
    hex.push(h);
  });

  return BigInt('0x' + hex.join(''));
}

function urlBase64ToBase64(str) {
  var r = str % 4;
  if (2 === r) {
    str += '==';
  } else if (3 === r) {
    str += '=';
  }
  return str.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
}

function base64ToUrlBase64(str) {
  return str.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');
}

function bnToB64(bn) {
  var hex = BigInt(bn).toString(16);
  if (hex.length % 2) { hex = '0' + hex; }

  var bin = [];
  var i = 0;
  var d;
  var b;
  while (i < hex.length) {
    d = parseInt(hex.slice(i, i + 2), 16);
    b = String.fromCharCode(d);
    bin.push(b);
    i += 2;
  }

  return btoa(bin.join(''));
}
```